# Comparing double variable with a integer value in C

Tags: c

I just wanted to compare a double number saved in a double variable in C and then compare it with value 1.
For example :

```
double x;
x = 1;
if(x == 1)
  call ....
```

but even when x has value one, this condition evaluated as false because x kept value 0.99999 instead of 1.

how can I manage this problem!!

Comment: And of course all time favorite http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: No. If `x` has value 1, `x == 1` will return true. If `x` is close to 1, but not equal to 1, it will evaluate to false.

Comment: What compiler are you using? On Windows with the Microsoft C compiler it returns true for me.

Comment: In many cases it's impossible, because on computers floating point values can be very inexact. See for example [this site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). For more help on comparing floating point numbers, see [this site](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).

Comment: If `x` *actually* is one this should evaluate to `true`.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck, _actually_ or _exactly_?

Comment: @unkulunkulu Either one or both ;)

Comment: @fvu, that's quite an advanced article, I don't know why everyone suggests it to beginners, I'm planning for two years now to read it again to understand more.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the new extended version of that article lives at http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: @AndreasBrinck, I mean, sometimes, when `x` is computed, it could _actually_ be 1, but not _exactly_ 1 :) 'Either 1 or both' lol

Comment: @unkulunkulu if x is set to 1, the expression x == 1  will be evaluate true. It's not a matter of double precision.

Comment: @Ben, yes, that's what I call _exactly_ 1.

Comment: @unkulunkulu because people should know what they're doing, and unfortunately FP math is not something you can really squeeze into a short 5-line kitchen recipe.  At least that article has survived peer review and is generally considered not to contain any of the common nonse you read about FP.

Comment: @unkulunkulu, ok but then the code provided by Hadi works fine.

Comment: @Ben, I'm not saying it doesn't work, it surprises me too that it gives any problems, maybe he oversimplified his actual code for this question and in reality `x` is being computed (that's what I called _actually_ one, i.e. ` | x - 1 | < eps `)

Comment: In suse linux gcc compiler, it condition is true only. Which OS and compiler you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a float so you need to take the precision into consideration:
if(x<1.000001 && x >  0.99999)

Comment: but what happened when we have both values, I mean 1 and for example 1.00000001, these two numbers are not exactly the same!!

Comment: @Hadi, yes, but you have to stick with that, because floating point numbers are not represented precisely in the computer anyway.

Comment: `fabs(x - 1) < 0.000001` is a more common idiom for this

Comment: @unkulunkulu Yes, they are, real numbers however are not.