# can't I use double in array?

Tags: c

what's problem here?
it shows a bug, help me I'm a beginner.
can I use double in array?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    double a;
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    double s[a];
    double b,c=0, d;
    for(b=0;b<a;b++){
    scanf("%lf",&s[b]);
    }
    for(b=0;b<a;b++){
    c = c + s[b];
    d=b+1;
    printf("%lf\n",c/d);
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Size of array can't be non-integer for obvious reasons.

Comment: Elaborating on Eugene's comment, the simplest/easiest way to fix this is: `int a; scanf("%d",&a);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
int a;
scanf("%d",&a);
```

Rest of your code is just fine .

Comment: Not a fan of making it a user-supplied signed `int`, since that may be negative

Comment: That same old problem . You need to use Integer , when you are accessing element using index . But you have declared variable 'b' as Double , that must be an Integer.

Comment: Mr. Govid good point . We can create a function of our own , for that .

Comment: I have edited the previous code and added function for that .

Answer (score 5):

In case it isn't clear, your array cannot be of double length. It's undefined behavior.

This is because a double is not an integer, but a rational number that *could be* an integer. A simple way to understand this issue is to take some floating point value, say 3.5.

What is an array of length 3.5 Is it 3 and a half slots of some size in contiguous memory? Is is enough slots for 3? 4? 3.5 slots would likely be useless and unintended, and if it's not a fractional slot, it might be unclear and likely unintended, hence undefined behaviour.

While the other people have proposed solutions creating an integral type, you cannot create an array of double length. You *can* create an array of doubles, ie

```
double arr[5];
```

But you can't create an array of double length like

```
int arr[3.3];
```

Comment: You can, but there can be issues - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189026/comparing-double-variable-with-a-integer-value-in-c

Comment: I didn't understand that, pls simplify if you can... Thanks in advance

Comment: A floating point number has finite precision and comparisons might not function as intended, but afaik it's well-defined and you can compare them.

Answer (score 2):

While variable length arrays are supported in modern C, the size of an array must be positive and integral.

What you could do instead is round to the nearest `size_t`:

```
size_t ASIZE = ceil(fabs(a));
double s[ASIZE];
```

Include `<math.h>` to access `ceil` and `fabs`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use floating-point types (`float` or `double`) to specify an array size or array index:

> #### 6.7.6.2 Array declarators
>
> **Constraints**
> 1 In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword **`static`**, the **`[`** and **`]`** may delimit
> an expression or **`*`**. **If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
> expression shall have an integer type**. If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
> have a value greater than zero. The element type shall not be an incomplete or function
> type. The optional type qualifiers and the keyword `static` shall appear only in a
> declaration of a function parameter with an array type, and then only in the outermost
> array type derivation.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

> #### 6.5.2.1 Array subscripting
>
> **Constraints**
> 1 One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to complete object *type*’’, the other
> expression shall have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘*type*’’.

<sup>*ibid.*</sup>

So `a` and `b` must be of integral type - I typically use `size_t` for array size and index variables:

```
size_t a;

printf( "Gimme the array size: " );
scanf( "%zu", &a );

double s[a];

for ( size_t b = 0; b < a; b++ )
  scanf( "%lf", &s[b] );
```

Comment: I find it a bit curious that the standard doesn't declare an array size given in an expression evaluating to a *negative* integral value to be undefined behavior. It is definitely something to avoid.

Comment: @GovindParmar: If the array size is a constant expression, then a negative value is a *constraint violation* and requires a diagnostic.  If it's not a constant expression, and is negative, then it is indeed undefined behavior (see 6.7.6.2/5).